# z3 incorrectly saying UNSAT

Tags: z3, smt

For the problem below, solution exists but z3 says UNSAT.

```
(set-logic QF_UFNRA)
(declare-fun a () Real)
(declare-fun b () Real)
(declare-fun c () Real)
(declare-fun d () Real)
(declare-fun e () Real)
(declare-fun f () Real)
(declare-fun g () Real)
(declare-fun h () Real)
(assert (and (<= a 1.0) (> a 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= b 1.0) (> b 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= c 1.0) (> c 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= d 1.0) (> d 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= e 1.0) (>= e 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= f 1.0) (>= f 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= g 1.0) (>= g 0.0)))
(assert (and (<= h 1.0) (>= h 0.0)))
(assert (= (* (+ a b) (+ a c)) a))
(assert (= (* (+ a b) (+ b d)) b))
(assert (= (* (+ a c) (+ c d)) c))
(assert (= (* (+ b d) (+ c d)) d))
(assert (= (+ a b c d e f g h) 1.0))
(check-sat)
```

Valid solution:

```
a = 1/12, b = 1/4, c = 1/6, d = 1/2, e = f = g = h = 0
```

I am not able to figure out why z3 says unsat.

z3 version is z3-4.3.0-x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the version of z3 on rise4fun (http://rise4fun.com/z3). I just tested it, and it says SAT. It returns the model you gave.

Comment: The latest version from github also gives the right answer. I guess the bug was fixed since 4.3.0 version.